# How to dismiss the UIActivityViewController on clicking the Cancel button?

Tags: ios, swift

```
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    let excludeActivities = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,UIActivityTypeMail,UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard]

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes=excludeActivities
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: activityVC)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController as UIPopoverPresentationController!
    activityVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0,150)
    popover.sourceView = self.view
    popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(345,580,0,0)
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm trying to dismiss the activity controller when cancel button is clicked but this is not working.
On clicking anywhere outside the controller,this gets dismissed but not by tapping cancel button.

Comment: what objectToShare  here ?

Comment: let objectsToShare = [imageURL]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this

```
let text = String(format:"Download the app on your iPhone")

// set up activity view controller
let objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [ text ]
self.activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
     activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

self.activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
// so that iPads won't crash

self.activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
 if success {
  // Success handling here
 }       
}
// exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
self.activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook ]

// present the view controller
self.presentViewController(self.activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```